# Can't seem to pass values in Intent when being passed through `PendingIntent`

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I am trying to create an alarm that pops up a notification at a specific time in the future. I have the code below and most of it seems to be working but for some reason, I can't seem to pass any values in the Intent object. I feel like I'm doing everything right. I've even looked at several online tutorials and as far as I can tell, I'm doing exactly the same thing they are doing, but theirs work and mine doesn't.

**Receiver.java**

```
package com.example.mytermtracker.notifications;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.mytermtracker.application.Date;

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "app: Receiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: now:     " + Date.now().toSQL());

        Channel channel = intent.getParcelableExtra("channel");
        if (channel == null) 
            throw new NullPointerException("Could not find the channel."); //<== the line that the breaks.

        String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        if (title == null) title = channel.NAME;

        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        if (message == null) message = "";

        int callerID = intent.getIntExtra("caller_id", 0);

        channel.show(context, title, message, callerID);
    }

    public static void setAlarm(Context context, Channel channel, String title, String message, Date trigger, int callerID) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Receiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("channel", channel);
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        intent.putExtra("caller_id", callerID);

        Log.d(TAG, "setAlarm : now:     " + Date.now().toSQL());
        Log.d(TAG, "setAlarm : trigger: " + trigger.toSQL());

        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent
                .getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (alarmManager != null) {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, trigger.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
        }
    }
}
```

**Channel.java**

```
package com.example.mytermtracker.notifications;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.example.mytermtracker.R;
import com.example.mytermtracker.application.Date;

import static com.example.mytermtracker.application.App.MANAGER;

public class Channel implements Parcelable {
    private static final String TAG = "app: Channel";

    public final String ID;
    public final String NAME;
    public final String DESCRIPTION;
    public final int IMPORTANCE;

    private Channel(NotificationManager manager, String id, String name, String description, int importance) {
        this.ID = id;
        this.NAME = name;
        this.DESCRIPTION = description;
        this.IMPORTANCE = importance;

        if (manager != null) {
            NotificationChannel termStartChannel = new NotificationChannel(ID, NAME, IMPORTANCE);
            termStartChannel.setDescription(DESCRIPTION);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(termStartChannel);
        }
    }

    protected Channel(Parcel in) {
        ID = in.readString();
        NAME = in.readString();
        DESCRIPTION = in.readString();
        IMPORTANCE = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<Channel> CREATOR = new Creator<Channel>() {
        @Override
        public Channel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Channel(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Channel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Channel[size];
        }
    };

    public static Channel create(NotificationManager manager, String id, String name, String description) {
        return new Channel(manager, id, name, description, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    }
    public static Channel create(NotificationManager manager, String id, String name, String description, int importance) {
        return new Channel(manager, id, name, description, importance);
    }

    public void show(Context context, String title, String message, int callerID) {
        Log.d(TAG, "show: now: " + Date.now().toSQL());
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        MANAGER.notify(callerID, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(ID);
        dest.writeString(NAME);
        dest.writeString(DESCRIPTION);
        dest.writeInt(IMPORTANCE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay. So I figured it out. Apparently `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` does something to the inputs that is messing it up. I just changed it to `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` and that seems to have fixed the issue.